# Is 50 mins enough time to catch international flight out of Boston Logan Airport?

Tags: airports, airport-transfer, boston

From the time I arrive at airport, is 50 mins enough to catch an international flight out of terminal E?  I have carry-on baggage only.  The official airport recommendations are always too conservative, as most of us know.

This would be a curb-side drop-off.  Time to walk through the front door and make it through Terminal E security.

**Update**: I ended up not risking it and will give myself 90 minutes since I'm new to the airport.

Thanks everyone

Comment: Are you arriving on a connecting domestic flight or are you proposing to drive up to the curb 50 minutes before departure time?

Comment: Do you have TSA Precheck?

Comment: Security queues are dependent on day-of-week and time-of-day. At 2 in the morning, I think you are OK. Friday afternoon? I don't think I would test this.

Comment: Of course, you would need to have been able to check-in online, which may or may not be an issue for an international flight (check with your airline), possibly depending on your destination and/or other details, as check-in desks will likely be closed when you get to them. So, what airline, what destination? Also, do you fly a premium class and/or have elite FF status?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe.

Security line length varies greatly during the day and can be anywhere from a few minutes to half an hour or more. There is no TSA PRE-check but there is a separate lane for premium customers (business, status, etc).

Check in lines can also be long, so do it helps to do online check in advance (provided it's allowed by the airline and not get snagged in doc check)

EDIT: the assumption of being there "exactly" 50 minutes is dicey as well. Traffic towards, inside and around the airport is bad during most times of the day and outright horrible during rush hours. Public transport (blue line, silver line) is fairly ineffective and also subject to traffic delays.

Comment: Are you sure there's no precheck there? [Their website](http://www.massport.com/logan-airport/at-the-airport/security-information/) lists them as an enrollment center.

Comment: @jdouglas There is no Precheck at BOS Terminal E. It is available at A, B, and C.

Comment: Even at airports that have Precheck, the ticket will often be through an international carrier that doesn't participate in the program so you can't use it anyway.